# How to get jsf datatable row index on mouse click without using checkbox or radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jquery-events, hxdatatableex

I have used JSF **hx:datatableEx datatable** component to display document list. Values for the table fetched from the database.

Now I want to add an **event** such that when user does ***"right click with mouse"*** on any row I have to display **context menu** for that particular row.

My question is how to get the **index of the clicked row?**.

Please help me to find solution.

**Code written to display document List, I listed only few columns:**

```
<hx:dataTableEx headerClass="headerClass" footerClass="footerClass" columnClasses="columnClass1, columnClass2" rowClasses="rowClass1,rowClass2" scrollSize="175px" styleClass="dataTableEx" value="#{pc_DocumentSearch.allDocumentsList}" var="varallDocumentsList" binding="#{pc_DocumentSearch.allDocList}" rows="25">
<hx:columnEx id="column1" align="left" width="10%">
    <h:outputText id="text6" styleClass="outputText" value={pc_DocumentSearch.allDocList.rowIndex+1}"></h:outputText>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText id="text2" styleClass="outputText" value="#{prop.SL_No}" </h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
</hx:columnEx>

<hx:columnEx id="column2" width="38%" align="left">
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText id="text5" styleClass="outputText" value="#{prop.Document_Name}">   </h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
<hx:outputLinkEx id="link1" styleClass="a" onmouseover="popup('ViewAttribute documentId=#{varallDocumentsList.DOCUMENT_ID}','#{sessionScope.attrCtrlOption}');" onmouseout="popupClose()" onmousedown="view_document(' {varallDocumentsList.DOCUMENT_ID}');">
<h:outputText id="text9" styleClass="outputText" value="#  {varallDocumentsList.DOCUMENT_NAME}"></h:outputText>
</hx:outputLinkEx>
</hx:columnEx>
                        
<hx:columnEx id="column3" width="12%" align="left">
<h:outputText id="text49" styleClass="outputText" value="  {varallDocumentsList.VERSION_NO}"></h:outputText>
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText id="text48" styleClass="outputText" value="#{prop.Version_No}"> </h:outputText>
 </f:facet>
 </hx:columnEx>

<hx:columnEx id="column4" align="left" width="20%">
<h:outputText id="text8" styleClass="outputText" value="#{varallDocumentsList.CREATION_DATE}">
<hx:convertDateTime />
 </h:outputText>
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText id="text4" styleClass="outputText" value="#{prop.Date}"></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
</hx:columnEx>

<hx:columnEx id="column5" width="10%">
<hx:outputLinkEx id="viewCommentLink" styleClass="a" onmousedown="view_doccomment('#{varallDocumentsList.DOCUMENT_ID}','#{varallDocumentsList.FOLDER_ID}');">
<h:outputText id="viewComment" styleClass="outputText" value="#{prop.View}">   </h:outputText>
</hx:outputLinkEx>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText id="text43" styleClass="outputText" value="#{prop.Comments}">  </h:outputText>
</f:facet>
</hx:columnEx>

<hx:columnEx id="attributeColumn6" rendered="false">
<h:outputText id="attributeText1" styleClass="outputText" value="#{varallDocumentsList.INDEX_VALUES}"></h:outputText>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText id="attributeHeader1" styleClass="outputText" value="Attribute Details"></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
</hx:columnEx>

</hx:dataTableEx>
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? And how are you creating your data rows in datatable?

Comment: Displaying document list is working. Just have to add client side event for server side component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solution I used to solve the problem:

First create context menu with desired options as follows:

```
<div id="cntnr">
<ul id="items">
    <li><a onclick="load()">Indexes</a></li>
    <li onclick="load()"><a>Delete</a></li>
    <li onclick="load()"><a>Forward</a></li>
    <li onclick="load()"><a>Share</a></li>
    <li onclick="load()"><a>Comments</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

To get the clicked row Id write the following code:
For more Information on this subject you should refer this [**Link**](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/06/using-datatables.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trs = document.getElementById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        trs[i].oncontextmenu = new Function("highlightAndSelectRow(this)");
    }
});
var docId=0;
var trAttri=0;
var Id=0;
function highlightAndSelectRow(tr) {
    var trs = document.getElementById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        if (trs[i] == tr) {
            Id=tr.getAttribute('class');
            } else {
            trs[i].style.bgColor = '#ffffff';
            }
    }
}
```

To clean up the context menu:

```
function startFocusOut() {
    $jq(document).on("click", function () {
      $jq("#cntnr").hide(5);
      $jq(document).off("click");           
    });
}
```

To bind the context menu:

```
$jq(document).ready(function()  {
    $jq("#tableIdDiv").bind("contextmenu", function (e)  {
        if(Id) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $jq("#cntnr").css("left", e.pageX);
          $jq("#cntnr").css("top", e.pageY);
          $jq("#cntnr").fadeIn(5, startFocusOut());
          Id=null;
        }
    });
});
```